# Concatenating JSON strings for POST request

Tags: ios, database, json, asihttprequest, concatenation

I'm attempting to submit a large database containing many tables to a web service by sending the data via JSON. Extracting the data and converting it to a JSON string is working fine but so far I have only implemented it to send one table at a time each with its own ASIHTTPRequest. My question is whether or not concatenating all the JSON strings generated from each table is a good idea or if I should first combine the tables in their abstract data form, before converting all of them together to JSON?

Alternatively if there is any other suggestion that would be good too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just "concatenate" JSON strings.  The result will not be legal JSON.  You need to somehow "splice" them.

And, of course, the server on the other end must be capable of parsing the resulting JSON -- it may only expect one table at a time, eg.

Comment: So you would suggest that adding each table to the same array and converting them all together would be the only approach here? There are some conflicting answers.

Comment: I think you first need to figure out what syntax the server will accept.

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on your needs. If the tables are unrelated, multiple requests may be more appropriate because if a request fails (timeouts or loss of connection), it won't affect any other requests. However if you have tables with associations with one another, it would be better to send it all in one go so either all the data transmitted wholly or did not so you don't end up with broken associations.

Comment: This sounds like an important consideration. If a table sent that has a relationship with another table fails to be sent in its entirety for whatever reason, that would most definitely result in database inconsistency and/or database problems.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any issue in doing any one of the two choices you proposed

But i would suggest concatenate the tables in the database before converting so that you dont deal with string concatenations and other form of processes